# std::string to char* without cutting bytes

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arduino, std

So, I'm using a BLE library to receive bytes from a mobile app, and I want to save these bytes in the SD Card of an ESP32 ("Arduino").

The BLE library is receiving the data in this format, as a `std::string`

```
std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();
```

When I receive the data, I'm doing a `Serial.println(rxValue.length())` to verify the size of chunks I'm receiving, I'm receiving **512 bytes** as expected, and it's indeed printing `512`

So, it's all good here, I'm receiving the 512 bytes I want, **the problem comes next**:

In order to save to the SD Card, the function that does the writing to the SD card asks me for a `char * message`

So I must convert the `std::string` into a `char *`, I'm doing it as follows:

```
const char *cstr = rxValue.c_str();
```

But whenever I do this, some bytes (that I believe that are bytes out of the alphanumeric/signs spectrum) are cut off, the length is no longer 512 after converting them into a char array, and I need them to be the same 512 bytes to write correctly to the SD card all the bytes.

To test this behavior, I'm printing the length of the `char *` to see if the 512 bytes are still there:

```
strlen(cstr)
```

But surprise! **They are not 512 bytes**, they are way less, so I'm doing something wrong when I try to convert the `std::string` to `char *`

What would be the correct method to transform a chain of bytes that comes in `std::string` into a `char *` without loosing bytes :-(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `std::string` may contain '\0' which will not be processed by functions that expect C string properly. You need to use different functions or remove '\0' from `std::string`. Another possible issue you modify `std::string` or let it die before you use result of `c_str()`. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Don't use `strlen` use `rxValue.size()`.

Comment: @Galik the ``strlen()` is being used in the `char *` tried to apply `size()` to the `char *` but it does not have that method

Comment: I would not use `cstr` just use `rxValue.c_str()` and `rxValue.size()` instead.

Comment: @Galik Thanks, just posted my answer of how I achieved it

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation is if the received string somehow contains the null-terminator `\0` somewhere in the middle of the received 512 bytes, which is why `strlen` would deduce the string length to be less than 512.

I would print out the value of the c_str character at the index returned by `strlen` and see if it is a null-terminator there.

Comment: The 512 chunks are coming from a streaming of a .bin file, I need to be able to write the .bin in the SD card. Basically I’m transfering a binary file, every byte is important, if it’s a null-termintator, I believe it’s part of the .bin file

Comment: It's hard to say how to modify your SD writing logic without seeing how it's currently being done and where it fails. But in essence, you have to somehow handle the unexpected null-terminator until you have written the number of bytes as returned by `rxValue.size()` as it is the source of ground truth about the number of bytes received.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it!

I ended up doing the following:

```
unsigned char cstr[rxValue.size()];
memcpy(cstr, rxValue.data(), rxValue.size());
```

And this is how it worked perfectly. Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is "cut off" or otherwise modified. What happens is that you use wrong function `strlen()`, which intended to work with C-style strings on pointer that points to arbitrary binary data.

As was explained above `strlen()` will return length of **text string** which ends with first `'\0'` character encountered in your data. But that doesn't mean that data is not there.

What you need to do, when calling some function which writes data, is to pass `rxValue.data()` as pointer (you can also use `rxValue.c_str()`, but using `data()` instead clearly show that you expect some "data" here, not "string") and `rxValue.size()` as size.